# Как поместить 2 переменных в href?

Tags: javascript, angular

Пытаюсь сделать динамическую гиперссылку и поэтому требуется поместить туда переменную.

ts:

```
 url1: string = 'test.com/search/q=';
```

html:

```
href="'url1' + {{user.id}}"
```

Данный метод не работает.

Comment: Что-то такое нужно `<a href="{{url1 + user.id}}">...</a>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular позволяет скомбинировать два разных текстовых поля следующими способами:

```
<a href="{{ url + userId }}">Ссылка</a>

<a href="{{ url }}{{ userId }}">Ссылка</a>
```

UPD:
Также можно сделать через pipe или компонент, если у вас все хранится в объекте.

ts-файл

```
export class AppComponent {
  user = {
    url: 'test.com',
    userId: '123s',
  };
}
```

html-файл

```
<a href="{{ user | urlGenerat }}">Ссылка</a>
```

pipe-файл

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'urlGenerat',
})
export class UrlGeneratPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return value.url + value.userId;
  }
}
```

Также можно сделать через отдельный компонент и передавать туда уже готовый объект:

Шаблон родителя

```
<user-link [user]="user"></user-link>
```

Шаблон дочернего компонента

```
<a href="{{ user.url + user.userId }}">Ссылка</a>
```

ts-файл:

```
export class UserLinkComponent {
  @Input() user;
}
```

При таком подходе, можно инкапсулировать всю логику внутри компонента, и она может быть гораздо сложнее.

Также, внутрь компонента с ссылками можно передавать observable в async-пайпом.

При таком подходе, можно будет реиспользовать компонент в других частях приложения.